# Convert string to char error message

Tags: c#

Cannot convert string to char error message. I am trying to be able to write a program that will, for example, allow the user to input 1800HIETHC and it will give them back all digits.
I am already stuck.... Any help or advise on what to do?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char number = ' ';
        int numb = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the telephone number...");
        number = Console.ReadLine();

        while (number <= 10)
        {

            if (number == 'A')
            {
                numb = 2;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(numb);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Other than handling 'A', what have you tried?  What are your results?  Any errors?  The info you provide and demonstrate your attempt at solving your own issue, the more likely it will be that you will get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Console.ReadLine gives you a `string`

a `string` is, among other things, a collection of `char`s

try this

```
string number = "";
int numb = 0;

Console.WriteLine("Please enter the telephone number...");
number = Console.ReadLine();

for(int i=0; i<number.Count; i++)
{
    if (number[i] == 'A')
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Console.ReadLine()` returns a string not a character. So you cannot assign it to the variable number.
Once you have assigned it to a string you can get characters out of the string by doing `myString[0]`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly,

```
string number = "1800HIETHC"; //Console.ReadLine() reads whole line, not a single char.

int[] nums = Digits(number);




static int[] Digits(string number)
{
    return number.Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit).Select(ToNum).ToArray();
}

static int ToNum(char c)
{
    int[] nums = { 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9 };

    if (char.IsDigit(c)) return c - '0';

    c = char.ToUpper(c);
    return nums[c - 'A'];
}
```