# The case, breaks, and loops with c#

Tags: c#

My application works if I type in 1 character, such as A. It will give me 10 2's,
but I want it to work on all 10 digits I type in. What am I doing wrong?
I want it so I can type in 1800HELLO2 and it will give me all digits.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = 0;
        string userInput;

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the 10 digit telephone number. ");
        userInput = Console.ReadLine();

        while (x < 10) 
        {
            switch (userInput)
            {
                case "1":
                    userInput = "1";
                    x++;
                    break;
                case "A":
                case "B":
                case "C":
                case "2":
                    userInput = "2";
                    x++;
                    break;
                case "D":
                case "E":
                case "F":
                case "3":
                    userInput = "3";
                    x++;
                    break;
                case "G":
                case "H":
                case "I":
                case "4":
                    userInput = "4";
                    x++;
                    break;
                case "J":
                case "K":
                case "L":
                case "5":
                    userInput = "5";
                    x++;
                    break;
                case "M":
                case "N":
                case "O":
                case "6":
                    userInput = "6";
                    x++;
                    break;
                case "P":
                case "Q":
                case "R":
                case "7":
                    userInput = "7";
                    x++;
                    break;
                case "S":
                case "T":
                case "U":
                case "8":
                    userInput = "8";
                    x++;
                    break;
                case "V":
                case "W":
                case "X":
                case "Y":
                case "Z":
                    userInput = "9";
                    x++;
                    break;
                case "0":
                    userInput = "0";

                    break;
            }


            Console.WriteLine(userInput);
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: -1: Have you even read answers to your previous questions like - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412528/convert-string-to-char-error-message : "a string is, among other things, a collection of chars"...

Comment: What behavior are you experiencing? What it a user entered lowercase characters or a character not in the list?

Comment: It looks like you're doing some school project and just need code ready for you. If it's not the case, read first few C# books before asking questions on StackOverflow please.

Comment: Yes this is out of a question from a school text book. No it is not assigned as school does not start for another week and no it is not for a grade. I read the other thread and I did not understand it nor found any use from it. Simply put its friday night and I do not know how to code a question and have been trying to figure it out on my own for a few hours now. I have read up to the middle chapters of this txt book.

Comment: I am at the point that I need help, an instructor, or someone who is willing to give me advice. Not rude, unbenign programmers who have apparently forgotten how it was when they programmed themselves for only 2 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
class Program
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = 0;
        string userInput;

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the 10 digit telephone number. ");
        userInput = Console.ReadLine();

        // Did the user type in more than 10 characters?
        if(userInput.Length > 10)
        {
            // Get the first ten letters, no matter how many letters the user entered
            userInput = userInput.Substring(0, 10);
        }

        // Force values to upper case for comparison
        userInput = userInput.ToUpper();

        string systemOutput = String.Empty;
        foreach(var c in userInput) 
        {
            switch (c)
            {
                case "1":
                    systemOutput += "1";
                    break;
                case "A":
                case "B":
                case "C":
                case "2":
                    systemOutput += "2";
                    break;
                case "D":
                case "E":
                case "F":
                case "3":
                    systemOutput += "3";
                    break;
                case "G":
                case "H":
                case "I":
                case "4":
                    systemOutput += "4";
                    break;
                case "J":
                case "K":
                case "L":
                case "5":
                    systemOutput += "5";
                    break;
                case "M":
                case "N":
                case "O":
                case "6":
                    systemOutput += "6";
                    break;
                case "P":
                case "Q":
                case "R":
                case "7":
                    systemOutput += "7";
                    break;
                case "S":
                case "T":
                case "U":
                case "8":
                    systemOutput += "8";
                    break;
                case "V":
                case "W":
                case "X":
                case "Y":
                case "Z":
                    systemOutput += "9";
                    break;
                case "0":
                    systemOutput += "0";
                    break;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(systemOutput);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your user input can be any number of characters (the `ReadLine()` function will read *N* characters until you press `ENTER`) but your `switch` statement doesn't check individual characters of your input - it only checks a number of 1-character strings.

This means that even if you type `1-800-333-1111`, you'll never check it because it's not a 1-character string like the various cases you have in the `switch`.

You need to iterate through each character one-by-one in the input string and check the individual *characters*. For example:

```
if ( userinput != null )
{
    userinput = userinput.ToUpper ();

    for ( int i = 0; i < userinput.Length; i++ )
    {
        switch ( userinput[i] )
        {
            case '1':
            case 'A':
                ...
                break;

            ...

            default:
                // Handle invalid characters here
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that the various case values are single characters (using the `'`), not 1-character strings.

Do note, that it's not a very good idea to hardcode the length of the phone number as a number in the code. Different users may enter the phone numbers differently - some may use spaces or dashes as separators, some may only enter the digit. In these cases the length of the input string will be different. Some users may even accidentally enter multiple spaces or put in `(` and `)` for the area code.

You should validate the input before you even check or you shouldn't rely on the number of input digits as you iterate through the input.

Comment: You may want to uppercase the input string before the loop.

Comment: @Cory Did that, thank you. At first I assumed the OP would use upper/lowercase `case` statements but that's just too inconvenient.

Comment: @ xxbbcc Meant that on another post ^above. Sorry

Comment: @Azzamean Ah, ok, I removed the comment.

Comment: Second the comment about the length.  My wife has a bunch of relatives that need 15 digits to dial directly.  By the time you count relays and access codes it's 29 digits.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach isn't really correct. You're switching on userInput every time, when really you want to check each character in the string. Study the code below:

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {


        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the 10 digit telephone number. ");
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        // Maybe do some validation here, check the length etc
        Char output;
        foreach (Char c in userInput) {
            switch (c) {
                case 'A':
                case 'B':
                case 'C':
                    output = '2';
                    break;
                case 'D':
                case 'E':
                case 'F':
                    output = '3';
                    break;
                case 'G':
                case 'H':
                case 'I':
                    output = '4';
                    break;
                case 'J':
                case 'K':
                case 'L':
                    output = '5';
                    break;
                case 'M':
                case 'N':
                case 'O':
                    output = '6';
                    break;
                case 'P':
                case 'Q':
                case 'R':
                    output = '7';
                    break;
                case 'S':
                case 'T':
                case 'U':
                    output = '8';
                    break;
                case 'V':
                case 'W':
                case 'X':
                case 'Y':
                case 'Z':
                    output = '9';
                    break;
                default:
                    output = c;
                    break;
            }

            Console.Write(output);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

We use a `foreach` loop so we aren't hard coding the length, which gives flexibility.

Comment: You may want to uppercase the input string before the loop.

Comment: I did, I am still studying the code. There are a few things I want to do to it but I am just soaking it in trying to understand it.

Comment: to stop the length at 10, would I do a do and while loop or just a while loop? which of those 2 types would you recommend

Answer (score 0):

You can take benefit of `Dictionary` for this purpose:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = 0;
    string userInput;

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the 10 digit telephone number. ");
    userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    Dictionary<string,string> dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    dict.Add("1","1"); 
    dict.Add("ABC2","2");
    dict.Add("DEF3","3");
    dict.Add("GHI4","4");
    dict.Add("JKL5","5");
    dict.Add("MNO6","6");
    dict.Add("PQR7","7");
    dict.Add("STU8","8");
    dict.Add("VWXYZ9","9");
    dict.Add("0","0");
    userInput = string.Join("",userInput.Select(c=>dict.First(k=>k.Key.Contains(c)).Value).ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine(userInput);
}
```

or even more concise:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = 0;
    string userInput;

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the 10 digit telephone number. ");
    userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    string[] s = "0,1,ABC2,DEF3,GHI4,JKL5,MNOP6,PQR7,STU8,VWXYZ9".Split(',');
    userInput = string.Join("",userInput.Select(c=>s.Select((x,i)=>new{x,i})
                                                    .First(k=>k.x.Contains(c)).i).ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine(userInput);
}
```